# Entity Framework Simple Report

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How would I write a query using entity framework where I need to make a list with a column for the product, category and parent category. I have not figured out how to get the parent category. Any Help is appreciated.
So far I have the following:

```
from product in Products
select new { Ctg = (from prdCategory in ProductCategories
                    where prdCategory.Products.Contains(product)
                    select prdCategory.CategoryName).FirstOrDefault(),
             Name = product.ProductName
             ParentCtg = ...
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify if "parent category" is a separate table or is a self reference column on ProductCategories table (like a ParentID FK on ProductCategory table that refers to ProductCategoryID PK)?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the parent is a self reference column in the same ProductCategories table. So it is one to many ProductCategoriesId:ParentProductCategoriesId. Each product has a category and each category can have parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if all the associations has been set up correctly from your database then that's going to be one easy query:

```
var product = from p in context.Products
              select new {
                 Name = product.ProductName,
                 CategoryNames = p.ProductCategories
                         .Select(c => c.CategoryName).ToList(),
                 ParentCategories = p.ProductCategories
                         .Select(c => c.ProductCategory2.CategoryName).ToList()
              };
```

When EF maps *Self-Referencing Associations*, it creates two relevant navigation properties named `ProductCategory1` and `ProductCategory2`. Neither of these names is particularly helpful, one of these navigation properties refers to the parent category or the 0..1 side of the relationship. The other refers to the children or the * side of the relationship. 

To understand which is which, right-click *ProductCategory1*, in the property window, the multiplicity for *ProductCategory1* is * (many), so *ProductCategory1* represents the navigation property for the children or subcategories (also it's of type `EntityCollection<ProductCategory>`) and the other one - *ProductCategory2* - represents parent category for this category and it's of type `ProductCategory`. For your query, we are interested in this one.

In addition - to make your query more readable - you can rename *ProductCategory1* to *Subcategories* and *ProductCategory2* to *ParentCategory*.

Comment: I just realized that it is actually a many to many relationship so I am actually getting p.ProductCategories which is an entity collection instead of p.ProductCategory.CategoryName

Comment: Ok, we'll take care of that, but the parent category is still a self reference column in the same ProductCategories table, correct?

Comment: Yes, the parent category for the category is a self reference column in the ProductCategories table.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my code and it should works for you based on what you described.

Comment: I only had to edit the last select to "pc => pc.CategoryID == product.ProductCategories.FirstOrDefault().ParentID" and it now works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your schema correctly, it should be a simple case of getting a plain list of Products, and your display list should just have a column with 'thisProduct.Category.Name' displayed.